# high cpu usage on 2811 router

Tags: cisco, router

there is high cpu usage and high intterupt rate on 2811 router while there is low rate traffic about 10 Mbit. How can i fix this problem. output of sh processes cpu sorted 5sec | exc 0.00 command that

```
CPU utilization for five seconds: 82%/80%; one minute: 42%; five minutes: 42%
 PID Runtime(ms)     Invoked      uSecs   5Sec   1Min   5Min TTY Process 
 182     1123064    20291509         55  0.79%  1.26%  1.24%   0 HQF Shaper Backg 
  19     1223404      345072       3545  0.55%  0.44%  0.44%   0 ARP Input        
   2       83312       17269       4824  0.39%  0.16%  0.27%   0 Load Meter       
 119      462956       93754       4937  0.15%  0.19%  0.20%   0 IP Input         
  64       90784      344541        263  0.07%  0.02%  0.02%   0 Netclock Backgro 
 151       52000      130817        397  0.07%  0.06%  0.07%   0 CEF: IPv4 proces 
 183      207784      847165        245  0.07%  0.07%  0.07%   0 RBSCP Background 
 260      103688      430250        240  0.07%  0.03%  0.02%   0 Atheros LED Ctro
```

Comment: 28xx-series routers are famous for allowing complex ACLs to impact their CPU performance - have you got any?

Comment: there are a few ACL configuration which include static route. but there is also vpn configuration to communicate center side 3945 router.is vpn config cause high cpu usage and interrupt?

Comment: Perhaps, they are very low power routers I'm afraid

Comment: Can I check station of power via command.

Answer (score 0):

Cisco provides a troubleshooting document for this issue, it's relatively useful.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/10000-series-routers/15095-highcpu.html